# Email form data to myself from the email entered into the email field

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I'm trying to work out a way where the form data submitted comes to me but instead of it saying in my mail program that the email is from myself it uses the email from the form as the from email.

I was using a mailer that did this, but it stopped working and they stopped updating it. I tried looking through the code and I can't figure out how it was done.

I also can't find much about my problem.

I am able to make forms that send the data to me from me. But I would like it to be to me from their email from the form.

html / contact.html

`<form id="contact-form" form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">`

php / send_form_email.php

````
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);```

Currently my website is example.com, someone enters details into my form with their own email, they submit the form and it comes to me from example.com as it's being sent from my server.

But I would like it to say from and then their email address from the form.
````

Comment: Don't do this; it's forgery and it will result in your messages being spam filtered or bounced. Put your own address in the from address, put theirs in a reply-to. Your code is also vulnerable to header injection, so it can be used as a spam gateway.  Since you tagged this with PHPMailer, I suggest you try using it, and base your code on the contact form example provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this, having your mail server claim it's sending mail from somewhere it isn't is a great way to get put on spam lists

Consider for example if someone email is bob@gmail.com, your server isn't gmail.com, and any mailserver that receives that email will check and see you're not gmail, and probably mark it as spam.

One solution would be to set the reply-to header to be their email, so while the email itself still comes from your server, any replies you make go to the intended recipient.

You could also set the display name to contain the email, eg:

"John Doe "  or something, that might work, though it still might get picked up and look spammy since you're essentially trying to mask the from address.